# How can I make MathJax render correctly within this script?

Tags: javascript, math, mathjax

I'm currently trying to learn JavaScript (since yesterday). As my first project, I attempted to write a program to solve quadratic equations with real roots. This can be seen here:

http://mathematicool.net/solve-quadratic.html

However, MathJax doesn't seem to be being applied to the code, since adding $ signs into this script does not express things in LaTex. What should I do to make it work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run MathJax after outputting the equation.
This is one way of doing that:

```
 MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub, document.getElementById(<ID OF DOM ELEMENT>)]);
```

Comment: Sorry, this is all very new to me, so you might have to be more specific. Do I just past that code anywhere in the head of the document, or do I need to put it somewhere else? Thanks for the help!